# convert multi-tiered PHP array to Javascript Object Notation

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a three-tiered PHP array with both numeric indices and key-value pairs. I would like to convert it to JSON, and reiterate through the object list. How would I do this? The PHP array is called `$main_array`, and appears as:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [STALL JEWELERS] => Array ([0] => 1760 [1] =>2004-03-15)
        [SALEMS JEWELERS] => Array ([0] => 2034 [1] => 2004-02-12)
    )
    [1] => Array(
        [AMBERS DESIGN] => Array ([0] => 300 [1] => 2000-11-15)
        [PINEFOREST] => Array ([0] => 1291 [1] =>2002-06-26)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `json_encode`?

```
echo json_encode($main_array);
```

Should output

```
[{"STALL JEWELERS":[1760,"2004-03-15"], "SALEMS JEWLERS":[2034,"2004-02-12"]},
 //second object here
]
```

In order to get it into your Javascript, you'll need either an AJAX call or you can output this directly into your `<script>` tag

```
<script>
var json = <?php echo json_encode($main_array) ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: Generally you don't `json_encode` it manually, because it's not transferred as json

Comment: Tried and works! However, it works within <?php ?> tags but not inside js <script> tags. I'm not sure how to access the list objects in Javascript and iterate through them